# Java: Dynamically create object from class name, with arguments

Tags: java, reflection

I have a Java class whose name is stored in a database, that I want to load at runtime. I am using reflection to try to do this, but the current code throws an InvocationTargetException:

```
String classname = "my.test.path.Class";
String details = "Some text";
Integer id = 123;

Class<?> cls = Class.forName(classname);
Constructor<?> cons = cls.getConstructors();
for (Constructor<?> con : cons) {
    System.out.println(con.toString()); // Does find the constructor
}
Constructor<?> constructor = cls.getConstructor(Integer.class, String.class);
ClassInterface object = (ClassInterface) constructor.newInstance(id, details);
```

The output of the System.out.println is:

```
public my.test.path.Class(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String) throws java.sql.SQLException,java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

The exception is as follows:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at test.path.Main...
```

This is the class where the code above is, not the constructor being called.

Comment: Please post output of  `System.out.println(con.toString());` and definition of `id, details` and the exception stacktrace

Comment: `[help-me]` `InvocationTargetException` usually means something went wrong inside *your* code, the code you're calling using reflection. In this case, the actual constructor. Please pay close attention to "Caused by" part of the exception dump.

Comment: this works for me, you should post the constructors definition of your class

Comment: Updated as requested

Comment: Arkadiy you are right, the exception pointed to the line where I was trying to create the class, but it was an exception being thrown in the constructor itself that was causing the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...)) the `InvocationTargetException` is thrown when an Exception happens during the execution of the constructor:

> InvocationTargetException - if the underlying constructor throws an exception.

Check if the arguments (id and details) are valid for your constructor and if they can generate exceptions.